# Swift Popover Anchor

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, popover, anchorpoint

I'm trying to show a popover over an image and I'm failing trying to point the anchor point to my image border (the image is the info icon).
Here is my code:

**The button action:**

```
@IBAction func infoTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "InfoPopOver", sender: nil)
    }
```

**And the prepare for segue:**

```
extension AddExpenseViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "InfoPopOver" {
            if let vctr = segue.destination as? MyPopOverViewController {
                vctr.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
                vctr.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
                vctr.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
                vctr.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = infoIcon.frame

            }
        }
    }

}

class MyPopOverViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 185, height: 80)

    }
}
```

Here a couple of screenshots:
[Main View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ0Fh.png)
[Popover shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwEMP.png)

The best I got was setting the coordinates manually, but it doesn't fit neither every screen type...

Comment: Try setting the `sourceView` to `infoIcon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change it to this:

```
vctr.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = infoIcon.superview
vctr.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = infoIcon.frame
```

That way you can be sure that you are using the superview of the infoIcon and the frame will be in the correct position.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!